# Remove Synonym Pairs using Min(ID)

Tags: mysql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/429f91/10

I have a Source Table from which I've gathered Synonym Pairs into a temp table e.g.

```
+-------+---------+--------+-----------+
| Name  | Synonym | NameID | SynonymID |
+-------+---------+--------+-----------+
| Yes   | Oui     |      1 |         2 |
| Yes   | Da      |      1 |         3 |
| Yes   | Si      |      1 |         4 |
| Oui   | Yes     |      2 |         1 |
| Oui   | Da      |      2 |         3 |
| Oui   | Si      |      2 |         4 |
| Da    | Yes     |      3 |         1 |
| Da    | Oui     |      3 |         2 |
| Da    | Si      |      3 |         4 |
| Si    | Yes     |      4 |         1 |
| Si    | Da      |      4 |         3 |
| Si    | Oui     |      4 |         2 |
| Red   | Rouge   |      5 |         6 |
| Rouge | Red     |      6 |         5 |
+-------+---------+--------+-----------+
```

with the goal of removing all but a single term from the source table so it has no synonyms. The SqlFiddle above contains the table and select yet I'm unclear how to

1. Group the synonyms (e.g in this case 'Yes', 'Oui', 'Da', 'Si' and 'Red', 'Rouge'
2. Select all BUT the Min(ID) for each group

In essence looking to do something like:

`Delete from SourceTable where ID in (SELECT QUERY FROM TEMP TABLE WITH ALL BUT MIN IDS FROM EACH GROUP`

which in this case would resul in

```
Delete from SourceTable where ID in (2,3,4,6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is: "There should not exist a synonym with a smaller ID" - This can be written as a NOT EXISTS subquery:

```
select distinct NameID
from Synonyms s
where not exists (
  select *
  from Synonyms s1
  where s1.SynonymID = s.NameID
    and s1.NameID    < s.NameID
)
```

This would return IDs 1 and 5.

Another way is

```
select distinct s.NameID
from Synonyms s
left join Synonyms s1
  on  s1.SynonymID = s.NameID
  and s1.NameID    < s.NameID
where s1.SynonymID is null
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sL6NvmfC1yvATKfLnLiQxb/0)

Getting the oposite result set is even simpler:

```
select distinct SynonymID
from Synonyms
where SynonymID > NameID
```

This will return 2,3,4,6